# emacs buffer color control characters

Tags: emacs, colors

I have one install of emacs that prints color characters instead of just changing the color, in some buffers.

`eshell` has correct colors, and so does my `*compilation*`, but the result of my `ack` search looks like this:

```
[1;32m/home/.../moveeval.cpp[0m
[1;33m44[0m:            [30;43mbest_coord[0m = test_coord;[0m[K
[1;33m47[0m:    return [30;43mbest_coord[0m;[0m[K

Ack finished at Wed Nov 27 09:20:46
```

I suppose it is some kind of minor mode I need to activate, but:

- I don't know which
- I didn't need to activate it in my other installs (on win7, for example. This is in Ubuntu).

What can I do to fix the colors, make the change automatic at every start, and why doesn't it work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

`ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on` should do the trick.

Add this to your setup to ensure this option is on:

```
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: I hoped so, but no. I tried both `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on` and adding the hook to `init.el` (and even restarting after that), but still no colors.